# helper returning an object not scalar value expected

Tags: ember.js

Thought I'd create a `if-then-else` helper which looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function ifThenElse(param, ifTrue, ifFalse=null) {
  return Boolean(param) ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(ifThenElse);
```

And then when using my component I can do the following:

```
{{my-nifty-component class=(if-then-else pigsHaveWings 'wake-up' 'good-answer') }}
```

Well the problem I'm having is that my helper is not very helpful and the HTML/DOM result is:

```
<div class="[object Object] ember-view"></div>
```

Can someone please help me with my helper?

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of Ember helper function gets one parameter and this parameter is an array of parameters, passed to helper. You need to rewrite your helper as

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function ifThenElse([param, ifTrue, ifFalse]) {
  return Boolean(param) ? ifTrue : ifFalse || null;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(ifThenElse);
```